# `proto3-json-serializer` doesn't map protobuf messages to proto3 json objects properly

Tags: javascript, serialization, proto3, protobufjs

I'm trying to upgrade the protobufjs package version from 6.11.3 to 7.2.4. But I noticed that message serialization part is not worked properly with latest protobufjs version.

I'm using npm package `proto3-json-serializer`(0.1.8) for the serialization part as follows.

```
    const serializerWrapper = {
     fromObject(object) {
      return serializer.fromProto3JSON(type, object);
     },
     toObject(message) {
      return serializer.toProto3JSON(message);
     },
    };
```

I'm just curious why this isn't worked with latest protobufjs version?

Also I noticed that there are two latest versions(7.2.4 latest, 6.11.4 latest-6) of protobufjs in [npm doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs/v/6.11.4?activeTab=versions). Does anybody know what's the differences between them?

Thanks in advance!